# How low multiple R-squared value is enough to reject a model?

Tags: regression

I'm doing a simple linear regression I tried:

```
> mod <- lm(rnorm(100,sd=2) ~ rnorm(100,sd=2.1))
> summary(mod)

Call:
lm(formula = rnorm(100, sd = 2) ~ rnorm(100, sd = 2.1))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0396 -1.0698  0.0803  0.9823  5.4893 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)            0.0280     0.1868   0.150   0.8812  
rnorm(100, sd = 2.1)  -0.1523     0.0900  -1.692   0.0939 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 1.868 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.02838,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.01846 
F-statistic: 2.862 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.09387
```

as you can see the multiple R-squared is very very low. I must to reject that model, but what is the level to understand if I can accept the model or not?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the p-value (0.09387) reported at the very end of the quotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did a linear regression of two random variables. You don't need to look at r-squared to reject that model.

In general, I would not reject/accept models based on r-squared or any other statistic, but on whether they make sense, add to knowledge, help answer questions and so on.

However, the "typical" values of r-squared vary from field to field. Generally higher in physical sciences and lower in social sciences/behavioral sciences

Answer (score 1):

Easy: when this value is not significant.
 You can for instance mix the order of values in predictors (in order to hold distribution) few times, build models on those datum sets and use the distribution of their R-squared values to show what is the probability that your model's R-square was scored by chance.